# Select items in listbox from array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, split, listbox

I currently have a cell with a list separated by commas (1, 2, 3) and the list isn't always the same amount of items. It can be up to 10 items.

I then have a listbox with items 1 - 10 in it.

I want to be able to select the specific items that are in the cell on a form with the listbox on it.

I have started by splitting the cell into an array like this:

```
Dim Array() As String
    Array= Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), ",")
```

But I can't figure out how to select items in my listbox that match the array.

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand your question. Can you please be a bit more clear. Are you expecting  to change no of values in list box based on the values present in the cell Some thing like if cell is 1,2,3 and list box should have only those 3 values and if cell is 3,4,5,7 list box should have these 4 values. Am i correct in my understanding. Also please share you code a little more

Comment: I want to select the items in the list box if they appear in the cell. So if cell A1 is 3,4,5,7. Then i want items 3 4 5 7 to be selected in the listbox on my form.

Comment: On what event you are expecting this to happen?

Comment: When the form is first opened so on the form initialize event

Comment: Sorry for too many questions. i Just want to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below Code. I tested it. It worked fine for me.

```
    Sub formdisplay()
    Dim valsToSelect
    valsToSelect = Split(Range("E6").Value, ",") 'E6 is my cell where i have my value in the form of 5,6,7,9
    For Each item In valsToSelect
    i = 0
        For Each listItem In UserForm1.ListBox1.List
            If CStr(listItem) = item Then
             UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True
             Exit For
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next
    Next

 UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```